# Fastest way in python to execute multiple URLs from a list and evaluate their body?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a text file of 100,000+ urls.
I want to execute all of them and evaluate their body response for certain text.
My current code does this but takes hours to complete.

Certain urls seem to slow down the process. Not sure how to skip them?
Just one URL takes over 10 seconds to fail, example below. 
error fetching ' https://www.example.com/ICD10': 
**urlopen error [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed**
Elapsed Time: 11.38811469078064

Here is my current code

```
text = "stackoverflow"
urls = open("urls.txt").read().splitlines()

def fetch_url(url):
    try:
        response = urlopen(url, timeout=2)
        return url, response.read(), None
    except Exception as e:
        return url, None, e

try:
    results = ThreadPool(300).imap_unordered(fetch_url, urls)
except:
    pass

for url, html, error in results:
    if error is None:
        if text.encode() in html:
            print("Found in " + url)
    else:
        print("error %r: %s" % (url, error))
```

Comment: Looks pretty good, with that many you may be restricted by bandwidth.  Might as well do the text evaluation in the fetch function if it's that simple.

Comment: How long does `results = ThreadPool(300).imap_unordered(fetch_url, urls)` take?

Comment: It takes 226 seconds for 626 urls to complete. Certain urls fails and take over 10 seconds to fail with "urlopen error [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed " error message.

Comment: I assume this is due to a DNS issue, since I can't ping them either. I am not sure if pinging them, before inserting them into the text file for evaluation, is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can, but it will still depend on your internet speed. The for loop at the end of your code make the ThreadPool useless. 
so I think you should do this instead.

```
urls = open("urls.txt").read().splitlines()

def fetch_url(url):
    try:
        response = urlopen(url, timeout=2)
        return url, response.read(), None
    except Exception as e:
        return url, None, e

def check_url(url):
    text = "stackoverflow"
    url, html, error = fetch_url(url)
    if error is None:
        if text.encode() in html:
            print("Found in " + url)
    else:
        print("error %r: %s" % (url, error))

try:
    ThreadPool(300).imap_unordered(check_url, urls)
except:
    pass
```

I think this way it will be faster because the ThreadPool is used correctly.

Comment: creating a list of 100,000 elements is small, and creating one is trivial. It happens practically instantaneously, and the memory management is fine.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is just to generalize it for huge lists of humongous sizes to not eat up a lot of the machine memory.

Comment: In any case, `imap_unordered` doesn't create a list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes it returns a generator, but this way the threads are used correctly the for loop in the OP code after calling ThreadPool function make it just run in one thread. doing it without the for loop will give faster results. the list was my mistake I didn't know that the map function returned a generator. i will edit my answer.